# Joi get schema from another model

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, joi

How to import a schema from another model with Joi?

Main class:

```
Lol = _dynogels2.default.define('Lol', {
                hashKey: 'userId',
                timestamps: true,
                tableName: 'Lol',
                schema: _joi2.default.object({
                    id: _dynogels2.default.types.uuid(),
                    userId: _joi2.default.string().trim().required(),
                    revisionDate: _joi2.default.number().required(),
                    verify: Verify.schema,
                    createdAt: _joi2.default.date().default(Date.now, 'time of creation').required(),
                    updatedAt: _joi2.default.date().min(_joi2.default.ref('createdAt')).required()
                }).unknown(true).options({ stripUnknown: true })
            });
```

SubClass:

```
Verify = _dynogels2.default.define('Verify', {
                hashKey: 'username',
                timestamps: true,
                tableName: 'Users',
                schema: _joi2.default.object({
                    id: _dynogels2.default.types.uuid(),
                    isVerified: _joi2.default.boolean(),
                    createdAt: _joi2.default.date().default(Date.now, 'time of creation').required(),
                    updatedAt: _joi2.default.date().min(_joi2.default.ref('createdAt')).required()
                }).unknown(true).options({ stripUnknown: true })
            });
```

I got this error: `Invalid schema content`

Edit:

If I use the schema as a var and import it, works:

```
var schema = joi2.default.object({
                        id: _dynogels2.default.types.uuid(),
                        isVerified: _joi2.default.boolean(),
                        createdAt: _joi2.default.date().default(Date.now, 'time of creation').required(),
```

Comment: What is this default object attached to _joi2?

Comment: @simon-p-r, it is a simple joi object.

Comment: It doesn't look like it is, I would user plain objects when constructing schemas.  You are mutating some value which cannot be seen from your example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `Invalid schema content` is referring to this `_dynogels2.default.types.uuid()`.  Is that referencing a compiled schema of `joi.string().uuid()`?  If it is not, then `Joi` doesn't know how to translate that into its ruleset.

Comment: this schema works pretty well. I have used it without importing and works.